# PHP variable from one php file to another using xmlhttp.open()

Tags: php, ajax

is it possible to get the variable from first php file to second php file by calling the second php file using `xmlhttp.open()`?

**First File:**

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

**Second File:**

```
$result_slots = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_slots);
```

I'm getting a Undefined error on the second file on `$conn` variable.

Comment: You need to include the first file from the second file: `include_once('database_connection.php');`

Comment: Hi @FrankerZ, the first file is calling the second file using xmlhttp.open(), theres a separate file also for defining the connectioninfo and servername (different file) but the connection is done the first file.